# List DOM Documents attributes and methods using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Just wondering if it's possible to print and list all methods and attributes available to the DOM document itself using Javascript?

So I would get something like so:

Document.doctype
Document.implementation
Document.documentElement
Document.createElement
Document.createDocumentFragment
Document.createTextNode
Document.createComment
Document.createProcessingInstruction
etc...
etc...

I want to do this to test on different browsers and not have to wade through mountains technical documents from each vendor to get accurate information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
for (var l in document.body){
  console.log("document."+l+":"+document.body[l]);
}
```

Comment: What about for example DOMImplementation.hasFeature, NodeList.length, etc or even Node? Are these interfaces not exposed to Javascript?

Comment: Actually I can get the Node constants for example Node.ELEMENT_NODE:1 but once it reaches its methods it returns Node.toString:function toString() { [native code] } It's the same for DOMImplementation, etc (but Document is fine.)

Comment: For DOMImplementation, enumerate on `document.implementation` and for Node likewise. To see properties inherited from the prototype chain, inspect Node.prototype